# Detect Android Browser used in Java

Tags: java, javascript, android, browser

I have a Javascript application that runs in Android.  It can only run in Google Chrome, not the default Android browser.  How do I detect the type of browser used by the Android device so that I can only run the application in Google Chrome?

Comment: You can't.  The best you can do is use Javascript to detect which browser they are using, and tell them they HAVE to use Chrome, and offer the means to download/install it.

Comment: Any reason the user agent string won't work?

Comment: What are you going to do when the user doesn't have Chrome installed?